# relocation R_X86_64_32S against

Tags: ensamblador, gcc, gnu

hola estoy programando en ensamblador y al compilar me muestra el error del titulo, este es todo el error que me genera

/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccbjmJPt.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.data' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile con -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: falló el enlace final: Sección no representable en la salida
collect2: error: ld devolvió el estado de salida 1

Utilizo la funciones de la libreria de c. Para  compilar ocupo

gcc hola.s -o hola

Tambien he probado lo siguiente

gcc -c hola.s

lo cual me genera un archivo hola.o y luego lo enlazo con

ld -share -fPIC -s -o hola hola.o

y me bota el mismo error, en otras maquina me compila a la perfeccion, mas en la que estoy trabajando actualmente no

Y el codigo

```
.global main
.text
main:
    mov   $msg, %rdi
    call  puts
    ret

msg:
    .asciz  "holaa"
```

Comment: ¿Código que te falla? ¿64 bits o 32 bits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El mensaje de error dice que es necesario que el código sea independiente de posición para generar un objeto compartido.

Para generar código independiente de posición (PIC), las referencias no pueden ser absolutas, deben ser relativas a algo conocido.

Para evitar saltos y llamadas a direcciones absolutas en alguna librería que no sabemos dónde se va a cargar, haremos llamadas indirectamente a través de la tabla de enlazado de procedimientos (PLT), que crea el enlazador dinámico. Esto se consigue, por ejemplo, usando `call puts@PLT` en lugar de `call puts`.

Para evitar referencias absolutas a datos, usaremos referencias relativas al contador de programa. Por ejemplo, en lugar de `mov $msg, %edi` (o equivalentemente `lea msg, %edi`), usaremos `lea msg(%rip), %edi`.

Nos queda:

```
.global main
.text
main:
        lea   msg(%rip), %rdi
        call  puts@PLT
        mov   $0, %rdi
        call  exit@PLT
        ret

.data
msg:
        .asciz  "holaa"
```