# Error en ensablador

Tags: ensamblador

Estoy programando en ensamblador mediante un IDE y me salta el siguiente error

```
 relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.data' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile con -fPIC
```

No sé si me puedan ayudar

Comment: Revisa si te ayuda esta pregunta. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/93516/relocation-r-x86-64-32s-against?rq=1

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y aquí te dejo un [mcve]